# $\tilde{H}_q(S^n)=0$ for all $q\neq n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

> **Definition.** A reduced ordinary homology theory $\tilde{H}_*$ consists of functors $\tilde{H}_q$ from the homotopy category of nondegenerately based spaces to the category of Abelian groups that satisfy the following axioms:
>
> > **DIMENSION.** If $X$ is a point, then $$\tilde{H}_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}\quad \text{and}\quad \tilde{H}_q(X)=0\quad \text{for all}\quad q\neq 0.$$
> > **EXACTNESS.** If $i:A\rightarrow X$ is a cofibraion, then the following sequence is exact:
> > $$\tilde{H}_q(A)\rightarrow \tilde{H}_q(X) \rightarrow \tilde{H}_q(X/A).$$
> > **SUSPENSION.** There is a natural isomorphism
> > $$\Sigma :\tilde{H}_q(X) \rightarrow \tilde{H}_{q+1}(\Sigma X).$$
> > **ADDITIVITY.** If $X$ is the wedge of a set of nondegenerately based spaces $X_i$, then the inclusions $X_i\rightarrow X$ induce an isomorphism　$$\bigoplus_i \tilde{H}_*(X_i) \rightarrow \tilde{H}_*(X).$$
> > **WEAK EQUIVALENCE.** If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a weak equivalence, then $f_*:\tilde{H}_*(X)\rightarrow \tilde{H}_*(Y)$ is an isomorphism.

To prove the Hurewicz theorem, I would like to show that

> If $X$ is a wedge of $n$-spheres, then $\tilde{H}_q(X)=0$ for all $q\neq n$.

By the additivity axiom, it suffices to say that $\tilde{H}_q(S^n)=0$, where $S^n$ is an $n$-sphere. I already know the following claim:

> For any $q\geq n$, $\tilde{H}_q(S^n)\cong H_{q-n}(*)$.

Here $*$ is the basepoint of $S^n$ and $H_*$ is the ordinary homology theory. If $q>n$, it follows immediately from the above. Therefore we need only check the case of $q<n$. But I could not do it. Is this purely deduced by the axioms?

For your information, I will state the reason why I would like to do. In the proof of the Hurewicz theorem, [this book](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf) says that $\tilde{H}_n(X)\cong \tilde{H}_n(X^{n+1})$ for any based CW complex $X$. Here $X^q$ is the $q$-skeleton of $X$. To do this, I consider the reduced exact sequence
$$\tilde{H}_{n+1}(X^{n+2}/X^{n+1})\xrightarrow{\partial}\tilde{H}_n(X^{n+1})\rightarrow \tilde{H}_n(X^{n+2}) \rightarrow \tilde{H}_n(X^{n+2}/X^{n+1}).$$
If the above was proved, $\tilde{H}_n(X^{n+2}/X^{n+1})$ and $\tilde{H}_{n+1}(X^{n+2}/X^{n+1})$ will be trivial, since $X^{n+2}/X^{n+1}$ is homotopic equivalent to $\bigvee_{j\in J}S^{n+2}$, where $J$ is the set of all $(n+2)$-cells. Then the exact sequence induces an isomorphism $\tilde{H}_n(X^{n+1})\rightarrow \tilde{H}_n(X^{n+2})$ as desired. Is this attempt impracticable? Might there be another way to do this?

Comment: Use the suspension axiom and induction.

Comment: I have already considered it, but I had no idea... Could you tell me how to use them?

Comment: First, for a reduced homology theory, the dimension axiom should give you the homology of $S^0$, because the reduced homology of a point is zero in all dimensions. So I think your axioms are wrong as stated. Anyway, once you have the homology of $S^0$, it should be easy.

Comment: It only proves the case of $q>n$, doesn't it?

Comment: It covers all $q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you know that
$$
\widetilde{H}_q(S^0) =
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} & \text{if $q = 0$,}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that "otherwise" also includes negative values of $q$. Then this is the base case for an induction proof that
$$
\widetilde{H}_q(S^n) =
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} & \text{if $q = n$,}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
The induction step invokes the suspension axiom and the fact that $S^{n+1} = \Sigma S^n$.

Comment: To do this, do I have to define the theory $\tilde{H}_*$ to fit all integers $q$? I have interpreted it as possitive integers.

Comment: It has to be for all integers $q$ because otherwise the suspension axiom won’t give complete information about the homology of a suspension. It will be zero when $q$ is negative.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.